# Cannot dismiss MFMailComposeViewController that I called from SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, skscene

I am trying to send an email from within my game app. In one of my SKScenes I have a sprite when you press it, it calls FeedbackVC().sendEmail(). This opens up the email viewController, but it does not dismiss properly. Here is my entire FeedbackVC class. I used the function getTopMostViewController because without it I was getting the error "Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!". My code will successfully open the MFMailComposeViewController with the prefilled fields and if I press the send button it actually will send to the email to my email, but it won't close and if I try to cancel the email it won't close either. Why won't my viewController close so it will continue back to my game after the email is sent or canceled?

```swift
import Foundation
import MessageUI

class FeedbackVC: UINavigationController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        var topMostViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        while let presentedViewController = topMostViewController?.presentedViewController {
            topMostViewController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topMostViewController
    }

    func sendEmail() {
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self

            mail.setToRecipients(["support@supportemail.com"])
            mail.setSubject("In-App Feedback")
            mail.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
            self.getTopMostViewController()!.present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            print("Failed To Send Email!")
        }
    }

    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have also tried setting the UINavigationControllerDelegate in the sendEmail() function.

```swift
mail.delegate = self as? UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

I have also tried things like popping the view controller and going back to the top most view controller in the mailComposeController.

```swift
popToRootViewContoller(animated: true)

getTopMostViewController()?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I've tried following the guide on, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, but it didn't work as I think my scenario is different since I am going from a SKScene to the MFMailCompose ViewController then back to a SKScene.

Comment: You need to call `dismiss` on the presenting view controller - I.e. the view controller you retrieved from `getTopMostViewController` - save that object in a property so that you can use it from the delegate method https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss

Comment: I tried initializing it at a class level with "var presentingVC = UIViewController()"
Then in my func getTopMostViewController I added "presentingVC = topMostViewController!" then in my fun mailComposeController i added "presentingVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)" but it still didnt dismiss the MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the other developers working on this project. Posting in case someone has similar problems.

We were attempting to call our FeedbackVC in a way that looked like this:

```
if nodeTapped.name == "Feedback" {
  let vc = FeedbackVC()
  vc.emailButtonTapped(foo)
}
```

This would create the FeedbackVC class, call the emailButtonTapped method, and then deallocate the class from memory upon exiting the if statement. This means that clicking cancel or send would attempt to access the deallocated space, causing an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I fixed this by declaring vc as a class variable instead of declaring it inside the if statement.